# Sutherland's law for other gasses

Tags: fluid-mechanics, aircraft-design

Sutherland's Law seems to be a fairly well-accepted relationship between dynamic viscosity and temperature and was originally created to work for ideal gases, though it is often extended to be used for atmospheric air.
$$
\mu = \mu_{ref}  \frac{T}{T_{ref}}^{3/2} \left(\frac{T_{ref} + S}{T+S}\right)
$$

$T_{ref} =$ reference temperature

$\mu_{ref} =$ viscosity at $T_{ref}$

$S =$ Sutherland temperature

My question is there any data or evidence to show that this formula is applicable for other gas mixtures and if so, what type of error should be expected?  Also, I'm not totally sure what the Sutherland temperature is here

My specific application is in the development of lifting surface designs for Mars and for Titan atmospheres which are very much not representative of Earth's.

Comment: I believe the S is also known as "Sutherland's constant", which I've only seen tabulated in reference sources (e.g. Crane TP 410, Perry's Chemical Engineer's Handbook).